# How to convert Matlab GUI into matlab code? i have a GUI i want a corresponding matlab code .m file

Tags: matlab, user-interface

i have a matlab GUI panel, i want to convert my GUI into matlab code for testing a code functionalities . please give suggestion for my problem.

Comment: You have to clarify your request and show what you have done.

Comment: Did you generate GUI using GUIDE? If so a Matlab script file with extension .m is also generated in parallel to that GUI , in order to make further updates.

Comment: ya sure but i hv gui in .exe format . i can be install but i am not able to get .m files

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional comment, I feel fairly certain that what you have is a compiled MATLAB GUI program. These programs are encrypted and cannot be decrypted. The only way you can get the code is to ask the person who compiled the program for an unencrypted copy.